# SQLite in R - error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ")"

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, rstudio, sqldf

Sorry for the basic question, but I am trying to run the following code with **sqldf** function in R, but every time it shows "Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ')': syntax error" and I can't find exactly where the error is.

I tried to indent/format in different ways but the error indication to "near ')'" persists all the time.

It seems all parenthesis are fine.

Code:

```
sqldf("

SELECT  Cia_2, Nombre_cia_2, N_orden_2, Tipo_orden_2, N_linea_2, N_direc_2, Nombre_alfa_2, Fecha_orden_2, 
           Surtido_programado_2, Original_prometida_2, 

           N_orden, Tipo_orden, N_linea, Cia, 

           Cant_recibida_2, Cant_pendiente_2, Cantidad_2, estado_sig_2, estado_ult_2, 
           (case when [N_orden_2] is null then 'SinOC' else 'ConOC' end) as TieneOC,

           (case when [Cant_recibida_2]=0 and [Cant_pendiente_2]=0 and [estado_sig_2]=999 then 'Anulada'
           else (case when [Cant_recibida_2] = [Cantidad_2] and [estado_sig_2] = 999 and [Tiene_OC_2] = 'SinOC' then 'Anulada' else 'NoAnulada' )) as Anulada,

           (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999999 then 'Normal'
            else (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999998 then 'Urgente'
                  else (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999997 then 'Emergente'
                        else (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999995 then 'Proyecto'                                                                              
                              else (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999994 then 'Importaciones' else 'Expost' ))))) as TipoReq,

          Unidad_negocios_2, 
          aprob_or_2.LastOfFecha_aprobac, 
          [SumOfOrden de Cambio_2]

          FROM bases_or_con_oc 
          LEFT JOIN aprob_or_2 ON (N_orden = aprob_or_2.N_orden_OR) 
                               AND (Tipo_orden = aprob_or_2.Tipo_ordenOR) 
                               AND (N_linea = aprob_or_2.N_lineaOR)
          WHERE  estado_sig_2 > 110
                               AND (case when [Cant_recibida_2] = 0 and [Cant_pendiente_2] = 0 and [estado_sig_2] = 999 then 'Anulada'
                                    else (case when [Cant_recibida_2] = [Cantidad_2] and [estado_sig_2] = 999 and [Tiene_OC_2] = 'SinOC' 
                                    then 'Anulada' else 'NoAnulada')) = 'noAnulada'
     ")
```

error image:
[image]

I also tried to exclude some lines in order to and find out the error point...

Do you know what's happening?

Comment: `CASE` statements do not need to be enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You have several case without end  each case must be a related  end

```
  sqldf("

  SELECT  Cia_2, Nombre_cia_2, N_orden_2, Tipo_orden_2, N_linea_2, N_direc_2, Nombre_alfa_2, Fecha_orden_2, 
             Surtido_programado_2, Original_prometida_2, 

             N_orden, Tipo_orden, N_linea, Cia, 

             Cant_recibida_2, Cant_pendiente_2, Cantidad_2, estado_sig_2, estado_ult_2, 
             (case when [N_orden_2] is null then 'SinOC' else 'ConOC' end) as TieneOC,

             (case when [Cant_recibida_2]=0 and [Cant_pendiente_2]=0 and [estado_sig_2]=999 then 'Anulada'
             else (case when [Cant_recibida_2] = [Cantidad_2] and [estado_sig_2] = 999 and [Tiene_OC_2] = 'SinOC' 
                    then 'Anulada' else 'NoAnulada' END) END ) as Anulada,

             (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999999 then 'Normal'
              else (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999998 then 'Urgente'
                    else ( case when [N_direc_2] = 35999997 then 'Emergente'
                          else ( case when [N_direc_2] = 35999995 then 'Proyecto'                                                                              
                                else (case when [N_direc_2] = 35999994 then 'Importaciones' else 'Expost'  END )  END) END)  END) END) as TipoReq,

            Unidad_negocios_2, 
            aprob_or_2.LastOfFecha_aprobac, 
            [SumOfOrden de Cambio_2]

            FROM bases_or_con_oc 
            LEFT JOIN aprob_or_2 ON (N_orden = aprob_or_2.N_orden_OR) 
                                 AND (Tipo_orden = aprob_or_2.Tipo_ordenOR) 
                                 AND (N_linea = aprob_or_2.N_lineaOR)
            WHERE  estado_sig_2 > 110
                                 AND (case when [Cant_recibida_2] = 0 and [Cant_pendiente_2] = 0 and [estado_sig_2] = 999 then 'Anulada'
                                      else ( case when [Cant_recibida_2] = [Cantidad_2] and [estado_sig_2] = 999 and [Tiene_OC_2] = 'SinOC' 
                                      then 'Anulada' else 'NoAnulada' END ) END) = 'noAnulada'
       ")
```

I hope I have not forgotten anyone

Answer (score 1):

Consider simplifying your SQL using the CTE clause, `WITH()`, supported by SQLite to avoid retyping same calculated column for *Anulada* in `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. And be sure to close all `CASE` statements with `END`:

```sql
WITH cte AS 
     (SELECT Cia_2, Nombre_cia_2, N_orden_2, Tipo_orden_2, N_linea_2, N_direc_2, 
             Nombre_alfa_2, Fecha_orden_2, Surtido_programado_2, Original_prometida_2, 
             N_orden, Tipo_orden, N_linea, Cia, 
             Cant_recibida_2, Cant_pENDiente_2, Cantidad_2, estado_sig_2, estado_ult_2, 
             CASE WHEN [N_orden_2] IS NULL THEN 'SinOC' ELSE 'ConOC' END AS TieneOC,
             CASE 
                 WHEN [Cant_recibida_2]=0 and [Cant_pENDiente_2]=0 AND [estado_sig_2] = 999
                 THEN 'Anulada'
                 ELSE 
                     CASE 
                          WHEN [Cant_recibida_2] = [Cantidad_2] AND [estado_sig_2] = 999 and [Tiene_OC_2] = 'SinOC' 
                          THEN 'Anulada' 
                          ELSE 'NoAnulada' 
                     END
             END AS Anulada,        
             CASE [N_direc_2] 
                  WHEN 35999999 THEN 'Normal'
                  WHEN 35999998 THEN 'Urgente'
                  WHEN 35999997 THEN 'Emergente'
                  WHEN 35999995 THEN 'Proyecto'
                  WHEN 35999994 THEN 'Importaciones' 
                  ELSE 'Expost' 
             END AS TipoReq,        
             Unidad_negocios_2, aprob_or_2.LastOfFecha_aprobac, [SumOfOrden de Cambio_2]

      FROM bases_or_con_oc 
      LEFT JOIN aprob_or_2 ON (N_orden = aprob_or_2.N_orden_OR) 
            AND (Tipo_orden = aprob_or_2.Tipo_ordenOR) 
            AND (N_linea = aprob_or_2.N_lineaOR)
      WHERE  estado_sig_2 > 110
     )

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE [Anulada] = 'NoAnulada';
```