# Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error in R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc, sqldf

My post similar with this
[SQLite in R - error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ")"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972937/sqlite-in-r-error-in-result-createconnptr-statement-near)
but desicion doesn't work

```
library("RODBC")
library("sqldf")
library("dplyr")

#connect to sql

dbHandle <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=MYNAME;database=AOtest;trusted_connection=true")

sql <- paste0 ("select * from  [AOtest].dbo.basisload1


               order by doc_date") 

ao <- sqlQuery(dbHandle, sql)



sqldf(";With CTE
AS
(
  select *,
  row_number() over (partition by [product_id],shop_code order by [doc_date])-row_number() over (partition by [product_id],shop_code,mark_1 order by [doc_date]) as grp
  from ao
),
CTE1
AS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM CTE c
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 grp as prvgrp
    FROM CTE
    WHERE mark_1 = 0
    AND doc_date <= c.doc_date
    and [product_id] = c.[product_id]
    and shop_code = c.shop_code
    ORDER BY doc_date DESC
  ) prev
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 grp as nxtgrp
    FROM CTE
    WHERE mark_1 = 0
    and [product_id] = c.[product_id]
    and shop_code = c.shop_code
    AND doc_date >= c.doc_date
    ORDER BY doc_date 
  ) nxt
)

SELECT c.product_id,c.shop_code,c.doc_date,c.ship_count,c.mark_1,case when med < ship_count then med when ship_count < 0 then 0 else ship_count end as output,
c.ship_count - case when med < ship_count then med when ship_count < 0 then 0 else ship_count end as output1
into test2
FROM CTE1 c
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT MAX(med) AS med
  FROM
  (
    SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ship_count <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE ship_count END) OVER (PARTITION BY [product_id],shop_code,grp) AS med
    FROM CTE
    WHERE grp IN (nxtgrp,prvgrp)
    and [product_id] = c.[product_id]
    and shop_code = c.shop_code
  )r
)c2
order by doc_date")
```

so the error

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error
```

How to avoid this error in my case.
Of course i could run this code from SQL Server Management Studio, but server where installed sql, all the time busy by other experts and other tasks, on my server only R.

Comment: Please find out which one of your SQL statements is the one with the syntax error by removing them one by one from your program.

Comment: Using consistent case & indentation would make your SQL statements less error-prone. e.g. https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/99d34ac456e25e46df23dd74fdee4d84

Comment: @hrbrmstr, during two days i try run you script from github, and get same error. What's wrong?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. It's just your script, just auto-indented.I (thankfully) never have to use Microsoft's horribad tech and I use `dbplyr` when connecting to external databases, not `sqldf()`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, 
this script good works in SSMS, but as i mentioned, SQL is busy by another users, can you suggest desicion with dbplyr, i don't insist on sqldf() –